# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/expression/BeanResolver

Tags: java, spring

I have spring-framework-3.0.0 ,Building a very basic app that simply reads in a simple bean configuration file. Appears to be a dependency issue as I am getting a NoClassDefFoundError , the following stack trace:

```
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.expression.BeanResolver
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
        ... 22 more
```

Library dependencies

```
commons-logging-1.1.1
org.springframework.asm-3.0.0
org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.
org.springframework.code-3.0.0.
org.springframework.context-3.0.0.
org.springframework.expression-3.0.0.
```

What am I missing? Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing 'org.springframework.**core**-3.0.0'. 
'org.springframework.**code**-3.0.0' - not aware of this library, probably a typo.

Comment: How did you get the 'org.springframework.code-3.0.0' dependency? It should most probably be 'org.springframework.core-3.0.0' one.